# Trim cells before comparison

Tags: excel

I am using a formula to sum a certain word from a filtered list on another sheet. I have the following formula and example of the data I am looking for:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET('Data'!R1,1,0)))*('Outage'!R:R="Birds"))
```

So what this formula does is go to the 'Outage' sheet and read a filtered Column R and looks for rows that have the word "Birds" and sums the occurrence and finally outputs it to a cell.

The problem I am having is that the data in Column R can have extra spaces in between. So for example, "Birds" would be "                Birds" or "[newline]Birds". I am getting the data from a HTML page so there can be extra spaces.

When Excel executes SUMPRODUCT, "[newline]Birds" does not equal "Birds" so it doesn't increment my count, which I need it to do. I have tried:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET('Data'!R1,1,0)))*(TRIM('Outage Data'!R:R)="Birds"))
```

But it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `TRIM` will only remove whitespace at the start and end of the cell data. You need to use `CLEAN` to remove non-printable characters. It may be that you need to use both if your data has newline and spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRIM` will only remove whitespace at the start and end of the cell data. You need to use `CLEAN` to remove non-printable characters.

It may be that you need to use both if your data has newline and spaces.

Office Ref - [CLEAN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/clean-HP005209014.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP003056131)

So in theory the following should work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET('Data'!R1,1,0)))*(TRIM(CLEAN('Outage Data'!R:R))="Birds"))
```

Comment: That did the job. Thanks!